# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется функция на питоне по сортировке смешанного списка, на отдельные 2 списка из документов и ссылок.

```
        list_fuze = ['https://www.npi-tu.ru//', 
        'http://media.npi-tu.ru', 'https://vk.com/club_npi', 
        'https://www.facebook.com/PSRSPU.NPI', 
        'https://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/2019/04/26/polozhenie_skan.PDF',
        'https://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2014/Politika-obrabotki-PDn.doc']



    def split_urls(list_fuze, doc_ext=('pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')):
            list_doc = []
            list_links = []
            _ = [list_doc.append(x) if x.lower().endswith(doc_ext)
                 else list_links.append(x)
                 for x in list_fuze]
            return list_doc, list_links

split_urls(list_fuze)
```

Но я только изучаю python, и мне совершенно не понятно как работает эта функция, а именно конструкция

```
_=[*]
```

c не прямым порядком циклов и условий. Буду благодарен советам или ссылкам, где можно узнать о подобном построении кода .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension

Comment: В аду питонистов есть отдельный котел для тех, кто так использует списковые выражения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это неправильное использование спискового выражения, оно соответствует циклу ниже, но при этом создает новый список из результатов выполнения `append`:

```
def split_urls(list_fuze, doc_ext=('pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')):
        list_doc = []
        list_links = []
        _ = [list_doc.append(x) if x.lower().endswith(doc_ext)
             else list_links.append(x)
             for x in list_fuze]
        return list_doc, list_links
```

Сгенерируемый список в итоге положили в переменную `_`, которая буквально означает, что она для ничего. Кст, `_ = [...]` создаст новый список из `None`, который ни для чего не нужен, занимает лишнее в памяти место и выглядит сложнее, чем простой цикл.

Нужно было через честный цикл выражаться:

```
def split_urls(list_fuze, doc_ext=('pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')):
    list_doc = []
    list_links = []
    for x in list_fuze:
        if if x.lower().endswith(doc_ext):
            list_doc.append(x)
        else:
            list_links.append(x)

    return list_doc, list_links
```

---

**PS.**

Подробнее об `_`. Это полезно для случаев, когда есть значения, что нужно куда-то поместить, но оно не нужно, например:

```
for key, value in [(1, 2), (2, 3)]:
    ...

# Если value не нужно, то проще так:
for key, _ in [(1, 2), (2, 3)]:
    ...
```

Или:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]

# Нужно только a
a, _, _ = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: *через честный цикл выражаться* - )))